# Problema en una vista laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, vistas

Como puedo mostrar la cantidad de Alumnos por Curso en una vista index??

[image: Vista de Cursos]

Estos son las relaciones en mis modelos
Alumno:

```
public function curso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Curso::class,'id_curso','id');
}
```

Curso:

```
public function alumnos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Alumno','id_curso');
}
```

Alguien que me ayude porfavor soy nuevo en esto, mi idea es un count de alumnos donde la id del curso sea igual al curso en cuestion, pero para eso necesito la ID del curso. este es mi controlador

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $cursos = Curso::search($request->nombre)->orderBy('nombre','ASC')->paginate(10);
    return view('cursos.index')->with('cursos',$cursos)->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si ya tienes la relación establecida, simplemente puedes utilizar el método `withCount()` para obtener el conteo de los elementos relacionados:

```
$cursos = Curso::search($request->nombre)->withCount('alumnos')->orderBy('nombre', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
```

En la vista, en las iteraciones:

```
{{ $curso->alumnos_count }}
```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: Gracias maestro